# C++ multiple string grabber(regex)

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost, boost-regex

I have problem with boost::regex, this solution works only for one result in each match

```
boost::regex regex("id=\"(.*?)\""); // should I use this "id=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)<value>(.*?)</value>"?
boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(xml.begin(), xml.end(), regex, 1); // 1 because I just need text inside quotes
boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
```

and now parsed string

```
<x id="first">
<value>5</value>
</x>
<x id="second"> 
<value>56</value>  
</x>  
etc...
```

Now question is how to parse id and value at once to grab them both inside matches loop

```
for( ; iter != end; ++iter ) {
  std::string id(iter->first, iter->second);
  std::string value(?????);
}
```

Comment: You'd better parse XML with DOM XML or somewhat, not with regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) contains a XML parser that you can use instead of regexes:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
...    
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;
read_xml(istreamOrFilename, pt);
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt) {
    std::string id(v.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.id"));
    std::string value(v.second.get<std::string>("value").data());    
}
```